# NSRegularExpression captured groups clarification

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a little problem understanding on getting captured groups using `NSRegularExpression`

```
let string = "QWERTY123 ASDFGH"
let nsString = string as NSString
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\D+)\\d+\\s(\\D+)", options: [])
let result = regex.matchesInString(string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))

print(result.count) // prints length of array
for r in 1..<result[0].numberOfRanges
{
    print(nsString.substringWithRange(result[0].rangeAtIndex(r))) // prints captured groups
}
for r in result
{
    print(nsString.substringWithRange(r.range))
}
```

So, when I print the length of `result`, I get `1`. It means the range of found expression should be in `result[0]`. But how come captured groups present in `result[0]`? Am I thinking something wrong?

Next one is, when I give regex as `(QWE)t` the captured groups loop crashes. How to return `nil` or something to indicate that there are no captured groups with the following regex?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `matchesInString` returns all matches of the regex (ignoring captured groups).
  In your example there is **one** match.
- The range at the first index of the match (`result`) is the matched range  of the regex without captured groups (`{0, 16}`).
- The ranges `1..<numberOfRanges` represent the ranges of the captured groups.
- If the regex doesn't match `result.count` is 0 and `result[0]` crashes because there is not first item.

Comment: Thank you for your help!